# Using variables inside a bash heredoc

Tags: bash, variables, sh, heredoc

I'm trying to interpolate variables inside of a bash heredoc:

```
var=$1
sudo tee "/path/to/outfile" > /dev/null << "EOF"
Some text that contains my $var
EOF
```

This isn't working as I'd expect (`$var` is treated literally, not expanded).

I need to use `sudo tee` because creating the file requires sudo.  Doing something like:

```
sudo cat > /path/to/outfile <<EOT
my text...
EOT
```

Doesn't work, because `>outfile` opens the file in the current shell, which is not using sudo.

Comment: This is an understandable confusion! As noted below, quoting any part of the delimiter turns off expansion in the heredoc (as if it were in `''`), but *not* quoting the delimiter turns expansion on (as if it were in `""`).
*However,* your intuition is correct in Perl, where a heredoc with single-quoted identifier behaves as if it were in single quotes, one with a double-quoted identifier as if in double quotes, and one with back-ticked identifier as if in backticks! See:
[perlop: <<EOF](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#%3c%3cEOF)

Answer (score 324, accepted):

In answer to your first question, there's no parameter substitution because you've put the delimiter in quotes - [the bash manual says](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Here-Documents):

> The format of here-documents is:
>
> ```
>       <<[-]word
>               here-document
>       delimiter
> ```
>
> No  parameter expansion, command substitution, arithmetic expansion, or
> pathname expansion is performed on *word*.  If any characters in *word* are
> quoted,  the  *delimiter* is the result of quote removal on word, and the
> lines in the here-document are not expanded.  If *word* is unquoted,  all
> lines  of  the here-document are subjected to parameter expansion, command substitution, and arithmetic expansion. [...]

If you change your first example to use `<<EOF` instead of `<< "EOF"` you'll find that it works.

In your second example, the shell invokes `sudo` only with the parameter `cat`, and the redirection applies to the output of `sudo cat` as the original user.  It'll work if you try:

```
sudo sh -c "cat > /path/to/outfile" <<EOT
my text...
EOT
```

Comment: If your interested you could also do this as: 
`(cat > /path/to/outfile) <<EOF` in place of the `sudo sh -c ... <<EOF`

Comment: Please tell me burried in Bash is a good reason why this is so.

Comment: @LandonKuhn, ...what part of this _needs_ a reason or justification? Sometimes you want heredoc contents to be literal, sometimes you don't.

Answer (score 132):

Don't use quotes with `<<EOF`:

```
var=$1
sudo tee "/path/to/outfile" > /dev/null <<EOF
Some text that contains my $var
EOF
```

Variable expansion is the default behavior inside of here-docs. You disable that behavior by quoting the label (with single or double quotes).

Answer (score 83):

As a late corollary to the earlier answers here, you probably end up in situations where you want *some* but not *all* variables to be interpolated.  You can solve that by using backslashes to escape dollar signs and backticks; or you can put the static text in a variable.

```
Name='Rich Ba$tard'
dough='$$$dollars$$$'
cat <<____HERE
$Name, you can win a lot of $dough this week!
Notice that \`backticks' need escaping if you want
literal text, not `pwd`, just like in variables like
\$HOME (current value: $HOME)
____HERE
```

Demo: https://ideone.com/rMF2XA

Note that any of the quoting mechanisms -- `\____HERE` or `"____HERE"` or `'____HERE'` -- will disable all variable interpolation, and turn the here-document into a piece of literal text.

A common task is to combine local variables with script which should be evaluated by a different shell, programming language, or remote host.

```
local=$(uname)
ssh -t remote <<:
    echo "$local is the value from the host which ran the ssh command"
    # Prevent here doc from expanding locally; remote won't see backslash
    remote=\$(uname)
    # Same here
    echo "\$remote is the value from the host we ssh:ed to"
:
```

Comment: https://www.snopes.com/fact-check/dear-rich-bastard/