# Here string SFTP isnt correctly parsing newline character

Tags: bash

I have a script which contains the following:

```
sftp $2@$3 <<< $"cd $4 \nput $5 \nbye"
```

which I pass variables too at runtime however, the `\n` characters are not rendered as new lines but are rendered as plaintext so the commands attempts to to the following:

```
sftp > cd $4\nput $5 \nbye
```

which is obviously a directory which doesn't exist, how can i make the new line characters persist?

if i dont parameterise the command it works fine eg.

```
sftp user@host <<< $'cd dir\n put file\n bye'
```

any ideas?

Maybe is due the the user of `'` vs `"` in the script?

Comment: `$"..."` is used for translatable strings; there is no equivalent to `$'...'` that allows for parameter expansion.

Comment: You can use `printf '%s\n' "cd $4" "put $5" "bye" | stfp $2@$3` or `stfp $2@$3 < <(printf '%s\n' "cd $4" "put $5" "bye")`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a `HERE` document to achieve mimicking interactive input:

```
#!/bin/bash

sftp $2@$3 << EOI
cd $4
put $5
bye
EOI
```

See http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html for examples, and [Using variables inside a bash heredoc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4937792/using-variables-inside-a-bash-heredoc) for a gotcha.

Comment: He doesn't *need* to use a here document, but it's certainly more readable (and portable) than cramming multiple lines into a single here string.

Comment: @chepner - heh, absolutely, no need - it was just one possible solution. For some reason I _needed_ to use the word _need_ - perhaps I was feeling _needy_...

Answer (score 2):

> Maybe is due the the user of ' vs " in the script?

Yes, that seems to be the case:

```
$ cat <<< $'foo\nbar'
foo
bar
```

but

```
$ cat <<< $"foo\nbar"
foo\nbar
```

I'm not sure what `<<<` and `$'...'` do in bash, but for your application, you should consider using a ['HERE document'](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html) like mentioned in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32909124/674064).