# How to create a bash script that creates a file and write variables inside (with sudo)?

Tags: git, bash, shell

I would like to make a bash script that will create a git-hook, so I can run `$ bash ./create-hook.sh example.com` and it creates this file:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
NAME="example.com"
TARGET="/var/www/${NAME}"
TEMP="/var/www/${NAME}_temp"
REPO="/srv/git/${NAME}.git"

mkdir -p $TEMP
git --work-tree=$TEMP --git-dir=$REPO checkout -f
rm -rf $TARGET/*
mv $TEMP/* $TARGET
rm -rf $TEMP
# etc.
```

```

So here is the current status of the script (not working):

```
#!/bin/sh

if [[ $# -eq 0 ]]
  then
    echo 'No name provided'
    exit 1
fi

sudo bash -c 'cat << EOF > post-receive
TARGET="/var/www/$1"
TEMP="/var/www/$1_temp"
REPO="/srv/git/$1.git"

mkdir -p \$TEMP
git --work-tree=\$TEMP --git-dir=\$REPO checkout -f
rm -rf \$TARGET/*
mv $TEMP/* \$TARGET
rm -rf \$TEMP
```

**How to pass the variable `$1` from the command line to the created file?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4938197/2112538) using `tee …` instead of `bash -c 'cat…`:

```
sudo tee > post-receive << EOF
TARGET="/var/www/$1"
# …
EOF
```

Answer (score 0):

the **<< EOF*** will write whatever is after it until you write EOF into the file so $1 will be sent just like that (textually `$1`) into the file. I guess you'll have to write the file by echoing:

`( echo TARGET='"/var/www'$1'"'; echo TEMP='"/var/www/'$1'_temp"'; echo REPO='"/srv/git/'$1'.git"'; etc etc ) > post_receive`

Or something along those lines