# how to run sqlite3 in bash script?

Tags: bash, sqlite, heredoc

I'd like to run series of sqlite commands in bash script:

```
db="main.sqlite3"
db2="sub.sqlite3"

sqlite3 ${db} <<EOF
attach ${db2} as m;
select count(*) from m.details;
.exit
EOF
```

when attach to a string, it works, but when it is a variable, it won't, got

```
Error: near line 1: near "/": syntax error
```

how to use a variable(db2) inside EOF? thanks

Comment: This should work as written. There is no `/` in the snippet you posted, so maybe you simplified it too much?

Comment: I suggest to check your file for special characters: `cat -A file` or `cat -v file`

Comment: Does the `attach` statement require the dbname to be quoted? Do you need `attach '$db2' as m;` ?? I can't tell from https://sqlite.org/syntax/attach-stmt.html and https://sqlite.org/syntax/expr.html

Comment: finally, that's the one works: sqlite3 ${db} <<EOF
attach '${db2}' as m;
select count(*) from m.details;
.exit
EOF

Comment: what you are really asking is this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4937792/using-variables-inside-a-bash-heredoc

Comment: @jrwren No, because that question is about quoting "EOF"...

Comment: Thanks @murphy you are right. The real issue is that attach doesn't accept parameter starting with / if it is unquoted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try putting the DB file to attach into double quotes:

```
attach "${db2}" as m;
```