# bash run script from here doc

Tags: bash, heredoc

In the code below, variable X is output normally.

```
# cat a.sh
X=world
echo 'hello' $X

# cat a.sh | bash
hello world
```

But, using here doc, variable X is not displayed.

```
# cat <<EOF | bash
> X=world
> echo 'hello' $X
> EOF
hello

# bash -s <<EOF
> X=world
> echo 'hello' $X
> EOF
hello
```

What made this difference?

Comment: The opposite problem (but the answer should still help you): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4937792/using-variables-inside-a-bash-heredoc

Answer (score 3):

You can see what happens when you remove the `|bash`

```
X=oldvalue
cat <<EOF 
X=world
echo "hello $X"
EOF
```

The `$X` is replaced before piping it to bash.
You can check the following

```
X=oldvalue
cat <<"EOF"
X=world
echo "hello $X"
EOF
```

This is what you want to execute:

```
cat <<"EOF" | bash
X=world
echo "hello $X"
EOF
```