# SSH EOF returns nothing when using subshell commands in a script

Tags: bash, shell, eof

I'm attempting to run a sequence of commands over SSH. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4412238/what-is-the-cleanest-way-to-ssh-and-run-multiple-commands-in-bash) inspired me to use EOF which seemed to work fine at first, but started acting up once I tried running subshell commands using $().

Anyone understand why this:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -tt abcdef@zxcv.net << EOF
    cd "$(ls -td -- ~/www/builds/* | head -n 1)"
    pwd
    composer install
    npm run installation
    npm run clean 
    npm run build 
    exit
EOF
```

Does this?

```
17-May-2019 10:29:26    Last login: Fri May 17 12:28:44 2019 from 82.148.198.138
17-May-2019 10:29:26    
17-May-2019 10:29:26        cd ""
17-May-2019 10:29:26        pwd
17-May-2019 10:29:26        composer install
17-May-2019 10:29:26        npm run installation
17-May-2019 10:29:26        npm run clean
17-May-2019 10:29:26        npm run build
17-May-2019 10:29:26        exit
```

The subshell returns blank when executed from a shell script, but works fine when executing it manually in a bash terminal. This happens without the double quotes as well.

I'm doing this on a Ubuntu server.

Comment: The subshell is expanded on your local machine rather than by the remote shell. Put your delimiter (EOF) in quotes (more info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4937792/using-variables-inside-a-bash-heredoc))

Comment: Quick fix: Change `<< EOF` into `<< 'EOF'`