# Unable to do a IF statement inside a bash heredoc

Tags: bash, shell, heredoc

I am trying to do a `IF..ELSE` inside a heredoc. The heredoc is necessary because the set of commands need to be executed as a different user.

Unfortunately, the `IF` statement doesn't work as expected, and always jumps to the `ELSE` clause. When I remove the `IF` block from the heredoc and place it outside it works as expected.

It is probably a simple thing I'm missing, but I have no idea what.

```
rem=0
function1 () {
    su - user1 <<'DONE'
        if [[ "$rem" -eq 0 ]];
        then
            echo rem is even
        else
            echo rem is odd
        fi
DONE

}

function1
```

It echoes rem is odd.

Comment: don't you get a syntax error using function like this? I would imagine you would need to `export rem` thou, and drop the `-`

Comment: thanks a lot! it works now... the exporting bit never occurred to me..

Comment: @jenesaisquoi yes, you're right, `function` shouldn't be used like that, it was a mistake I made while changing my code for copying in here. fixed it now in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Change the 3rd line of your script with this:

```
su - user1 <<DONE
```

Notice the missing quotes around DONE.
With quotes around the delimiter you basically deactivate the parameter substitution and the value of `$rem` is not what you expect it to be (just echo it and see). Without the quotes, the parameter substitution works.

Tested on a CentOS 7 with Bash 4.2.46.

See also a longer discussion here: [Using variables inside a bash heredoc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4937792/using-variables-inside-a-bash-heredoc)

Comment: if you do this, would later changes to `rem` have any effect on the result of the function call?

Comment: @jenesaisquoi I'm not sure what you mean. Give me a concrete example. Or better, open a new topic on this.

Comment: I wasn't sure if bash would evaluate the function definition only once, substituting the value of `rem` into the body, thus making all subsequent function calls return the same result, regardless of later changes to `rem`

Comment: after a quick test it would seem bash actually reevaluates the function with each call, however (surprising to me), so disregard my comment