# bash: How to get <current path> in the content of the 'cat' create-file command

Tags: bash, sh, cat

The shell script below creates a new file "foo.conf" with the content specified between the EOF tags.

```
#!/bin/sh
cat > foo.conf << EOF
DocumentRoot "./search.bin"
EOF
```

The created file contains the following content:

```
DocumentRoot "./search.bin"
```

But I need to have the full path of the current directory instead (where my shell script resides), for example:

```
DocumentRoot "/home/me/search.bin"
```

Is this even possible?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you looking for `$(pwd)/...`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using variables inside a bash heredoc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4937792/using-variables-inside-a-bash-heredoc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this :

```
#!/bin/sh
cat > foo.conf << EOF
DocumentRoot "$(readlink -f ./search.bin)"
EOF
```

You can replace

```
readlink -f
```

by

```
realpath
```

Answer (score 0):

Heredocs with an unquoted first word allow for pretty much full variable and other expansion. So you can do

```
#!/bin/sh
cat > foo.conf << EOF
DocumentRoot "$(pwd)/search.bin"
EOF
```

Comment: Note that `$PWD` is much faster to run than `$(pwd)`, and similarly POSIX-defined.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy. Thanks. TIL that PWD is a posix thing