# Create a SQL script within a bash script

Tags: mysql, linux, bash, shell

I'm trying to bootstrap a mysql using a rudimentary bash script

```
cat <<EoF > /tmp/mysql-load-table.sql
CREATE DATABASE  IF NOT EXISTS `web_customer_tracker`;
USE `web_customer_tracker`;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `customer`;

CREATE TABLE `customer` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `first_name` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

LOCK TABLES `customer` WRITE;

INSERT INTO `customer` VALUES 
    (1,'JeanLuc','Picard','picard@tng.com'),
    (2,'William','Riker','riker@tng.com'),
    (3,'Beverly','Crusher','crusher@tng.com'),
    (4,'Geordi','LaForge','laforge@tng.com'),
    (5,'Data','Android','data@tng.com');

UNLOCK TABLES;
EoF
```

The above works fine if I enter these commands directly into MySQL, however when I run it as part of a bash script, I get the below errors

```
-bash: web_customer_tracker: command not found
-bash: web_customer_tracker: command not found
-bash: customer: command not found
-bash: customer: command not found
-bash: customer: command not found
-bash: first_name: command not found
-bash: last_name: command not found
-bash: email: command not found
-bash: customer: command not found
-bash: customer: command not found
-bash: customer: command not found
```

Can't figure out what am I missing here, any help would be appreciated. I want to create this as SQL script and then pass it to mysql to create database and load it with data.

Comment: most likely backtick != single-quote

Comment: how do you start the bash script ?

Comment: According to https://stackoverflow.com/a/4938197/10622916 you should quote the delimiter to avoid substitution: `cat <<"EoF" > /tmp/mysql-load-table.sql`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quote your heredoc delimiter, e.g.

```
cat <<'EoF' > /tmp/mysql-load-table.sql
CREATE DATABASE  IF NOT EXISTS `web_customer_tracker`;
USE `web_customer_tracker`;
...
EoF
```

From [man bash](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash):

> No parameter and variable expansion, command substitution, arithmetic
> expansion, or pathname expansion is performed on word. **If any
> characters in word are quoted, the delimiter is the result of quote
> removal on word, and the lines in the here-document are not expanded.**
> If word is unquoted, all lines of the here-document are subjected to
> parameter expansion, command substitution, and arithmetic expansion,
> the character sequence <newline> is ignored, and \ must be used to
> quote the characters , $, and `.