# Import Environment Variable value into a file Shell Script

Tags: linux, shell

I have an 12.sh file with the below code

```
cat > /home/12.txt << "EOF"
[Unit]
${OUTPUT}
EOF
```

OUTPUT is an environment variable i want to import its value into the 12.txt file when i execute 12.sh file

Any one can tell how to do , Thanks in advance

Comment: You have to drop double-quotes around `<< EOF`!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I write a heredoc to a file in Bash script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2953081/how-can-i-write-a-heredoc-to-a-file-in-bash-script)

Comment: See [Using variables inside a bash heredoc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4937792/using-variables-inside-a-bash-heredoc)

Comment: @DsydShi : From the man page, section _Here Documents_ : _If **any part of word is quoted**, the delimiter  is  the result  of  quote removal on word, and **the lines in the here-document are not expanded**._ . IMO, it's counter-intuitive, but it's defined in that way.

Comment: @DsydShi : Just noticed that you are not using bash. But for POSIX shell is the same. [Here](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_07_04) is the official explanation for your case.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use cat, just echo the data required are redirect the output to the file

```
echo -e "[Unit]\n$OUTPUT" > /home/12.txt
```

Comment: Can you remove the full path of 12.txt from the answer @Raman Sailgopal

Comment: OK, I've changed it to match your example.