# how to display $ in bash script

Tags: bash, heredoc

I have a script. I can't print $ in a screen.

```
#!/bin/bash

SERVER_IP=""
PASSWORD=""
DOMAIN=""
CONFIG_CONTENT=$(cat << EOF

server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    root /home/webmas/$DOMAIN;

    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name $DOMAIN;

    location / {
            try_files \$uri \$uri/ =404;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
            include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
            deny all;
    }
}

EOF
)

ssh -tt -p 300 webmas@$SERVER_IP << EOF

mkdir $DOMAIN
cd /etc/nginx/sites-available
echo -n "$PASSWORD" | sudo -S sh -c "echo '$CONFIG_CONTENT' | tee /etc/nginx/sites-  available/$DOMAIN >/dev/null"

EOF
```

$uri is not displayed on the screen

I don't understand why `\$` don't help. Single quotes didn't help either. I've run out of ideas.

Comment: Where did you put the `\$`? Seems to me like it should work. Anyways, instead of having to pipe a multi-line string into another heredoc going into ssh, I'd try doing `scp` to copy the file and then `ssh sudo mv <...>`

Comment: location / {
            try_files \$uri \$uri/ =404;
        }
here I use \$

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using variables inside a bash heredoc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4937792/using-variables-inside-a-bash-heredoc)

Comment: This may be easier with less code, and only one here document, no ssh for easier testing, plus current output and expected output... the proverbial [mcve].  See also [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's simplify the problem. Start with a small heredoc:

```
var1=a
var2=b
doc=$( cat <<EOF
$var1 \$var2
EOF
)
echo "$doc" # prints: a $var2
```

Okay, so far so good. The escaped variable wasn't expanded.

`ssh` adds a layer of complexity to the problem, so let's skip it for a moment. Instead we'll use `cat` to inspect how the heredoc we want to pass to `ssh` actually looks after expansions.

```
cat <<EOF
sh -c "echo '$doc'"
EOF
# prints: sh -c "echo 'a $var2'"
```

Oops, I see a problem. Even though `$var2` is inside single quotes in the program that we want to pass to `sh`, that double quoted string has to be parsed first to create the program that `sh` receives and `$var2` will be expanded at that point. If you copy `sh -c "echo 'a $var2'"` into a terminal and run it you'll see the output is `a b`.

So, now that we know the problem, what are the solutions?

You could manually add extra escaping to the original document:

```
doc=$( cat <<EOF
$var1 \\\$var2
EOF
)
echo "$doc" # prints: a \$var2
cat <<EOF
sh -c "echo '$doc'"
EOF
# prints: sh -c "echo 'a \$var2'"
sh -c "echo 'a \$var2'" # prints a $var2
```

You could pass the document as an argument to `sh` instead of directly injecting it into the command string which would remove a layer of interpretation:

```
doc=$( cat <<EOF
$var1 \$var2
EOF
)
echo "$doc" # prints: a $var2
cat <<EOF
sh -c 'echo "\$1"' _ '$doc'
EOF
# prints: sh -c 'echo "$1"' _ 'a $var2'
sh -c 'echo "$1"' _ 'a $var2' # prints: a $var2
```

You could also look at the "automatic requoting" feature documented in [BashFAQ/096](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/096) or, as another user suggested, place the document in a file and `scp` it to the host instead of trying to work around the multiple levels of interpretation happening with your heredoc.

Answer (score 1):

Use the *quoted* way on *here document*:

```
foobar<<'EOF'
$XYZ
EOF
```

if you need ko keep expansion for some variables:

```
foobar<<EOF
\$XYZ # not expanded
$XXX  # expanded
EOF
```

Comment: but I also have names like $DOMAIN that need to be disclosed

Comment: What do you mean by 'disclosed' ?

Comment: the domain value should be substituted instead of $DOMAIN

Comment: If you have litteral `$foo`, use simple `EOF` and use backslash: `$foo`

Answer (score 0):

So, I found the answer. Because of the `cat`, the script tried to substitute the value twice. The first time in `cat`, the second time when writing to the file itself. Therefore, I had to screen `$` twice. The `'\$'` structure helped. That is, I used both quotation marks and a backslash at once. It worked.